# Cannot work out why I am getting this error.|TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: numpy, typeerror

I have a project for school and I need to get the historical data from Yahoo Finance and hen perform some calculations on it and write a report on it.

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import pandas_datareader as pdr


def dataanalysis(stock1, comp1, comp2, comp3):  # Function to download data from Yahoo
    stk1 = pdr.get_data_yahoo(str(stock1), start="1999-11-01", end="2019-11-01")  # Downloading 20 years of data
    cmp1 = pdr.get_data_yahoo(str(comp1), start="1999-11-01", end="2019-11-01")
    cmp2 = pdr.get_data_yahoo(str(comp2), start="1999-11-01", end="2019-11-01")
    cmp3 = pdr.get_data_yahoo(str(comp3), start="1999-11-01", end="2019-11-01")

    stk1.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)  # Put dem badboys in descending order
    cmp1.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)
    cmp2.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)
    cmp3.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)

    stk1['Returns'] = (np.log(stk1['Close'] / stk1['Close'].shift(-1)))
    cmp1['Returns'] = (np.log(cmp1['Close'] / cmp1['Close'].shift(-1)))
    cmp2['Returns'] = (np.log(cmp2['Close'] / cmp2['Close'].shift(-1)))
    cmp3['Returns'] = (np.log(cmp3['Close'] / cmp3['Close'].shift(-1)))

    stk1.to_csv(str(stock1) + '.csv')  # Out putting data to csv files
    cmp1.to_csv(str(comp1) + '.csv')
    cmp2.to_csv(str(comp2) + '.csv')
    cmp3.to_csv(str(comp3) + '.csv')

    stk1_returns = list(stk1['Returns'])  # Creating a list from the 'Returns' column
    cmp1_returns = list(cmp1['Returns'])
    cmp2_returns = list(cmp2['Returns'])
    cmp3_returns = list(cmp3['Returns'])

    del stk1_returns[-1], cmp1_returns[-1], cmp2_returns[-1], cmp3_returns[-1]

    stk1_ret_avg, cmp1_ret_avg, cmp2_ret_avg, cmp3_ret_avg = np.average(stk1_returns), np.average(cmp1_returns), np.average(cmp2_returns), np.average(cmp3_returns)
    stk1_volit, cmp1_volit, cmp2_volit, cmp3_volit = np.std(stk1_returns), np.std(cmp1_returns), np.std(cmp2_returns), np.std(cmp3_returns)

    tickers = ["", str(stock1), str(comp1), str(comp2), str(comp3)]
    averages = ["Averages = ", stk1_ret_avg, cmp1_ret_avg, cmp2_ret_avg, cmp3_ret_avg]
    volatility = ["Volatility = ", stk1_volit, cmp1_volit, cmp2_volit, cmp3_volit]
    correlations = np.corrcoef([stk1_returns, cmp1_returns, cmp2_returns, cmp3_returns])

    data_analyzed = [tickers, averages, volatility, correlations]
    # print(data_analyzed)
    return data_analyzed


def print_results(group):
    ticker_list = list(group[0])
    with open(str(ticker_list[1]) + " and Comp"".csv", "w") as group_anal:
        groupCSV = csv.writer(group_anal)
        for i in range(3):
            groupCSV.writerow(group[i])
        for i in range(2):
            groupCSV.writerow([])
        groupCSV.writerow(["Correlation Matrix"])
        groupCSV.writerow(ticker_list[1:5])
        for r in group[3]:
            groupCSV.writerow(r)


group1 = dataanalysis("AAPL", "AMZN", "INTC", "MSFT")  # Running the function
# group2 = dataanalysis("BARC.L", "BK", "GS", "DB")
group3 = dataanalysis("BRK-B", "ALL", "PGR", "MKL")
group4 = dataanalysis("MCD", "SBUX", "YUM", "WEN")
# group5 = dataanalysis("TSCO.L", "CA.PA", "SBRY.L", "WMT")
group6 = dataanalysis("WWE", "DISH", "DIS", "CMCSA")
print_results(group1)
# print_results(group2)
print_results(group3)
print_results(group4)
# print_results(group5)
print_results(group6)
```

This runs no problem, but if I include the other commented out group2 and 5 I get the following error:

```
File "C:/Users/HHF/OneDrive/Programming/Python/Assignments/Final Assignment/Financial Records/calculations.py", line 62, in <module>
    group2 = dataanalysis("BARC.L", "BK", "GS", "DB")
  File "C:/Users/HHF/OneDrive/Programming/Python/Assignments/Final Assignment/Financial Records/calculations.py", line 40, in dataanalysis
    correlations = np.corrcoef([stk1_returns, cmp1_returns, cmp2_returns, cmp3_returns])
 "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'" error.
```

I have tried everything I can think of and nothing works. If I remove all the tickers with a period symbol it works, but I am not sure why this is the case because if I print stk1_returns it seems to be a regular list.

Thank you so much for any help you can give me.

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to help.  A fuller traceback might help, since it could identify which operation is doing this divide.  Then some how you need to figure out what is different about the `group2`.  Is some data missing?  different size?  What is a list when it should be something else (like an array)?

Answer (score 0):

**One of the things you are passing to `np.corrcoef` is not what you think it is.**

For example, this throws the same error:

```
import numpy as np
np.corrcoef([[[1,2,3,4]], [4,5,6,7]])
```

Notice that the first 'array' is actually a list of one list. Maybe the bit where you cast `stk1['Returns']` etc to lists is going wrong. (I would stick to arrays if I were you.)